# Checking out svn repository without .svn files

Tags: svn, centos, repository, export, svn-checkout

I have an svn repository on my dedicated server (Centos 5.5) at /var/svn/myRepository. I just want to copy those files into my production folder /var/www/myWebapp.

As far as I am understanding SVN I could only use svn export on my local project folder which has all the sourcecode and additional .svn files. But on my dedicated Server I just have the repository. How can I get the sourcecodefiles, without those .svn files out of that repository into my /var/www/myWeapp folder?

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. You don't need a working copy to do a `svn export`.

Just do:

```
$ cd /var/www/myWebapp
$ svn export URL
```

You should get a clean copy of `HEAD` into `/var/www/myWebapp`.

Comment: That's right, you don't need a working copy. The other answers aren't completely wrong, but the checkout they suggest is unneeded (and creates the .svn-files)

Answer (score 1):

Just check-out your project in a "work" folder somewhere on your dedicated server. There is no problem to do that.

Then just do an "svn export" as your are used to.

Comment: @JB Jansen: Possibly you might edit/update your question in order to reflect the findings from the post of Pablo Santa Cruz.