# SVN check out linux

Tags: linux, svn

My uname -a reads :

```
root@edu [~]# uname -a
Linux edu.educationlinked.com 2.6.18-028stab068.3 #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 20:21:42 MSK 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am not sure which Linux OS is this?

I already have a repository hosted at a free repository and i use Tortoise SVN on windows as the client. I need to do the check out etc on a Linux machine mentioned above.

I have read and read and got confused about what to use? Can someone please help me.

Comment: Try `cat /etc/issue` to see which distribution you have.

Comment: According to `MSK` time zone, this might be one of the Russian GNU/Linux distros, e. g. [ALT Linux](http://www.altlinux.ru). Actually this question belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you just run `uname -a`? If so, you might have some trouble checking out anything from Subversion, since your clock is *way* off, and I believe subversion uses timestamps for some things. Otherwise, the existing answers will help you out.

Comment: @PaulFisher: that timestamp shows the build time of the kernel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking out svn repository without .svn files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195665/checking-out-svn-repository-without-svn-files)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There should be `svn` utility on you box, if installed:

```
$ svn checkout http://example.com/svn/somerepo somerepo
```

This will check out a working copy from a specified repository to a directory `somerepo` on our file system.

You may want to print commands, supported by this utility:

```
$ svn help
```

`uname -a` output in your question is identical to one, used by [Parallels Virtuozzo Containers for Linux 4.0 kernel](http://kb.parallels.com/8080), which is based on Red Hat 5 kernel, thus your friends are `rpm` or the following command:

```
$ sudo yum install subversion
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use **checkout** or **co**

```
$ svn co http://example.com/svn/app-name directory-name
```

**Some short codes:-**

1. checkout (co)
2. commit (ci)
3. copy (cp)
4. delete (del, remove,rm)
5. diff (di)